# Using rank to calculate various averages

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My data looks like this

```
+------+--------+------+-------+
| year | month  | name | value |
+------+--------+------+-------+
| 2017 |      1 | John |   100 |
| 2017 |      2 | Doe  |   200 |
| 2017 |      3 | Jane |   300 |
|    . |      . | .    |     . |
| 2018 |      1 | John |   150 |
| 2018 |      2 | Doe  |   250 |
| 2018 |      3 | Jane |   350 |
+------+--------+------+-------+
```

I am trying to calculate average of top 2 names for each year and month. I can do that with the below code

```
select year, month, avg(sum_value) as avg_of_2
from (
    select year,
             month,
             name,
             sum(value) as sum_value,
             rank() over (partition by year, month order by sum(value) desc) as rnk
      from database.table_a
      group by year, month, name
      order by 1, 2, 4 desc
    ) tbl_for_2
where rnk <= 2 -- for top 2 values
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;
```

But now I want to extend the average from top 2 names to top 5,10, and 50. Is there a way I can do it using rank without repeating the same query?

My final result would be like

```
+------+-------+----------+----------+---------+
| year | month |  avg_2   |  avg_5   | avg_10  |
+------+-------+----------+----------+---------+
| 2017 |     1 | some_val | some_val | som_val |
| 2017 |     2 | some_val | some_val | som_val |
|   .. |       |          |          |         |
|   .. |       |          |          |         |
+------+-------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: The easiest but dirty is to duplicate the query many times changing `where rnk <= 2` and joining everything on `year` and `month`

Comment: @AlexLarionov I'm currently doing that but I suspected there must be a better way to do this. Hence my post here.

Answer (score 1):

no way to return dynamic number of columns, all columns must be written.
just use the filtered aggregation in outer query:

```
select year, month, 
  AVG(sum_value)FILTER(WHERE rnk<=2) as avg_2,
  AVG(sum_value)FILTER(WHERE rnk<=5) as avg_5,
  AVG(sum_value)FILTER(WHERE rnk<=10) as avg_10,
  .................
  AVG(sum_value)FILTER(WHERE rnk<=100) as avg_100,
  ... and so on
from (
    select year,
             month,
             name,
             sum(value) as sum_value,
             rank() over (partition by year, month order by sum(value) desc) as rnk
      from database.table_a
      group by year, month, name
    ) tbl
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;
```